# Using Reduce to join outputs of lapply into a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, lapply

I am using lapply to repeatedly apply a function "response" to a series of dataframes, and then trying to merge the output into a new dataframe with the columns renamed.

It works when I do it in separate steps, but I'd like to combine it into pipes. When I run the following code, I get the error as shown.

```r
plist <- list(SOM_V, SOM_SD, SOM_C, SOM_L, SOM_M, SOM_KD, SOM_MP, SOM_SvD)

plist %>% 
  lapply(response, p = "f76a") %>% 
  Reduce(function(df1,df2) full_join(df1,df2, by = "y"), ) %>% 
  setnames(old = colnames(results), new = c('y','Vänsterpartiet','Socialdemokraterna','Centerpartiet','Liberalerna', 'Moderaterna', 'Kristdemokraterna', 'Miljöpartiet', 'Sverigedemokraterna'))

##Error Message

Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object '.' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Could anybody help me out?

Comment: You forget a dot, i.e. `%>% Reduce(function(df1, df2) full_join(df1, df2, by = "y"), .)`

Comment: Thanks. If I add a dot, I get ```Error in is.data.frame(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default``` error

Comment: Which line does the error occur at? `lapply` or `Reduce` or `setnames`? Btw are you sure you don't have a typo on `setnames`? What package is this function definded in?

Comment: I think the error is in the setnames line. I basically want to rename all the columns of the data.frame with a list of names. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could use `%>% setNames(c('name1', 'name2', ...))`